# Are there professional studios that are available to take pictures of sculpture?

Tags: product-photography, studio

I have built this sculpture, but I do not have the right lighting equipment or camera to take a really professional picture of this sculpture. But I need to submit a picture of it to the local museum to be on display right away and this requires a really nice picture.

Does anyone know if there are studios or services that can help to take a picture of these every day object?

Comment: Some idea of your general location may produce answers that are more useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find something like this in your area, but it's not a "commodity" find.  Your best bet might be to start with places serving artists -- coworking areas, workshops, "maker" spaces, etc. -- these are areas where other people are creating things, so they've very likely got the same problem you do.  One of these areas might have a stage / cubby / etc. set up do to what you're talking about, or they may know someone who could help you.

Next best, try local photographers -- any good photographer can do what you're talking about, but having one set up a custom setup just for you will cost real $$$.  You'd like to find someone who's already got the capability for you to bring your stuff in and shoot it for a reasonable fee.

Answer (score 1):

Anything<sup>1</sup> is available if you pay enough money. Contact a few local photographers (try "photographer *[your location]*" in your favourite search engine) and tell them what you're after - no need to worry about finding a studio or anything like that as they probably know more about what's available in your local area than you do.

1. within reason.

Comment: Ok, so as I suspected there doesn't exist like an "organization" just for this type of service

Comment: In any case how do you get a hold of these local photographers? Craigslist?